# How display the count of associates at each rating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called associate_ratings with the below structure:

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
associate   varchar(10) NO          
skill_id    int(11) NO  MUL             
rating  int(11) NO          
updated_time    datetime    NO
```

This table holds the skills(`skill_id`) of the associate and their corresponding `rating` in that skill.
Rating column can take values (1,2,3)
I want to get the in each skill how many associates have got a particular rating, please find below output table structure:

```
Skill_id  Rating1_count Rating2_count  Rating3_count

Java        2             1               4
C#          3             2               2
```

This says in Java there are 2 associates with rating 1,  1 associates with rating 2 &  4 associates with rating 3

I tried the below query, but the output is not in the format I expect:

```
SELECT skill_id, rating, count(*) FROM associate_ratings a
WHERE updated_time = (
   SELECT max(updated_time)
   FROM skill_set.associate_ratings b
   WHERE a.associate = b.associate
) GROUP BY a.skill_id, a.rating order by a.skill_id, a.rating;
```

Could you please let me know how to get the output in the format I want?

Comment: do you really need above query both for oracle11g and mysql database?

Comment: I just need a query. The db I am working on is mysql.
I guess the query would be more or les similar for different db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use temporary table and case

```
SELECT  skill_id, sum(rating_1), sum(rating_2), sum(rating_3)
    FROM (
     SELECT a.skill_id as skill_id, 
            case a.rating when '1' then 1  else 0 end  as rating_1,
            case a.rating when '2' then 1  else 0 end  as rating_2,           
            case a.rating when '3' then 1  else 0 end  as rating_3
    FROM associate_ratings a
    WHERE updated_time = (
       SELECT max(updated_time)
       FROM skill_set.associate_ratings b
       WHERE a.associate = b.associate
    ) ) as t
 GROUP BY skill_id
 ORDER BY skill_id;
```

Comment: I got the below error when I run this query:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case a.rating when '2' then 1  else 0 end  as rating_2                         c' at line 5

Comment: Missing column separator comma .. i have update the naswer

Answer (score 0):

```
select Skill_id  , 
  count(case when rating = 1 then 1 else null end) as Rating1_count ,
  count(case when rating = 2 then 1 else null end) as Rating2_count ,
  count(case when rating = 3 then 1 else null end) as Rating3_count 
from associate_ratings  b
left join associate_ratings  a
  on b.Skill_id = a.Skill_id
group by Skill_id
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    skill_id, 
    sum(IF(rating=1,1,0)) as Rating1_count, 
    sum(IF(rating=2,1,0)) as Rating2_count, 
    sum(IF(rating=3,1,0)) as Rating3_count
FROM associate_ratings 
GROUP BY skill_id
ORDER BY skill_id;
```

I think it's the most simple solution possible here.